# Inicio de sesion con FaceBook

Tags: php, javascript, facebook-api

Estoy tratando de realizar la conexión con FaceBook desde mi aplicación web pero no esta funcionando, anteriormente funcionaba correctamente.

Esta es la manera en que declaro el script en la plantilla padre por así decirlo ya que estoy usando el modelo `MVC` de `PHP`

```
<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      appId      : 'id_app',
      cookie     : true,
      xfbml      : true,
      version    : 'v3.0'
    });

    FB.AppEvents.logPageView();   

  };

  (function(d, s, id){
     var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
     if (d.getElementById(id)) {return;}
     js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
     js.src = "https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk.js";
     fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
   }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
</script>
```

y lo mando todo al JS que se llama registroFacebook.js donde coloco lo siguiente

```
/*=============================================
BOTÓN FACEBOOK
=============================================*/

$(".facebook").click(function(){

    FB.login(function(response){

        validarUsuario();

    }, {scope: 'public_profile, email'})

})

/*=============================================
VALIDAR EL INGRESO
=============================================*/

function validarUsuario(){

    FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){

        statusChangeCallback(response);

    })

}

/*=============================================
VALIDAMOS EL CAMBIO DE ESTADO EN FACEBOOK
=============================================*/

function statusChangeCallback(response){

    if(response.status === 'connected'){

        testApi();

    }else{
        console.log("response", response);
        swal({
          title: "¡ERROR!",
          text: "¡Ocurrió un error al ingresar con Facebook, vuelve a intentarlo!",
          type: "error",
          confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
          closeOnConfirm: false
        },

        function(isConfirm){
            if (isConfirm) {    
                window.location = localStorage.getItem("rutaActual");
            } 
        });

    }

}

/*=============================================
INGRESAMOS A LA API DE FACEBOOK
=============================================*/

function testApi(){

    FB.api('/me?fields=id,name,email,picture',function(response){

        if(response.email == null){

            swal({
              title: "¡ERROR!",
              text: "¡Para poder ingresar al sistema debe proporcionar la información del correo electrónico!",
              type: "error",
              confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
              closeOnConfirm: false
            },

            function(isConfirm){
                if (isConfirm) {    
                    window.location = localStorage.getItem("rutaActual");
                } 
            });

        }else{

            var email = response.email;
            var nombre = response.name;
            var foto = "http://graph.facebook.com/"+response.id+"/picture?type=large";

            var datos = new FormData();
            datos.append("email", email);
            datos.append("nombre",nombre);
            datos.append("foto",foto);

            $.ajax({

                url:rutaOculta+"ajax/usuarios.ajax.php",
                method:"POST",
                data:datos,
                cache:false,
                contentType:false,
                processData:false,
                success:function(respuesta){

                    if(respuesta == "ok"){

                        window.location = localStorage.getItem("rutaActual");

                    }else{

                        swal({
                          title: "¡ERROR!",
                          text: "¡El correo electrónico "+email+" ya está registrado con un método diferente a Facebook!",
                          type: "error",
                          confirmButtonText: "Cerrar",
                          closeOnConfirm: false
                        },

                        function(isConfirm){
                            if (isConfirm) {    

                             FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){

                                 if(response.status === 'connected'){     

                                    FB.logout(function(response){

                                        deleteCookie("fblo_300012410734892");

                                        setTimeout(function(){

                                            window.location=rutaOculta+"salir";

                                        },500)

                                    });

                                    function deleteCookie(name){

                                         document.cookie = name +'=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';

                                    }

                                 }

                             })

                            } 
                        });

                    }

                }

            })

        }

    })

}

/*=============================================
SALIR DE FACEBOOK
=============================================*/

$(".salir").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();

     FB.getLoginStatus(function(response){

         if(response.status === 'connected'){     

            FB.logout(function(response){

                deleteCookie("fblo_300012410734892");

                console.log("salir");

                setTimeout(function(){

                    window.location=rutaOculta+"salir";

                },500)

            });

            function deleteCookie(name){

                 document.cookie = name +'=; Path=/; Expires=Thu, 01 Jan 1970 00:00:01 GMT;';

            }

         }

     })

})
```

pero en la función `statusChangeCallback` no entra en el response de "connected" y pasa inmediatamente al mensaje de error y en la consola me aparece un `status unknow`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Lo estas corriendo en Chome ?

Comment: @LucianoMontañez en FireFox

Answer (score 0):

Esto no me sucedio con FB pero si con otras API´S

El problema en común era que se cambio la configuración de chrome para bloquear las cookies y los datos de tercero. Simplemente, desactive esta configuracióny funciono.

**Chrome -> Configuración -> Configuración Avanzada -> Privacidad y seguridad -> Configuración de contenido -> Cookies -> Desmarcar "Bloquear cookies de terceros"**

Podrías chequearlo con chrome con dicha configuración.

En caso que esto sea correcto, deberías hacer lo mismo con tus otros navegadores.

Comment: En chrome de hecho tengo deshabilitada la opción que me indicas